# The setter function can not be triggered in chrome

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

```
<input type="text" id="test">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test=document.getElementById("test");
    Object.defineProperty(test.style,"width",{
        set:function(){
            alert(1);
        }
    });
   test.onfocus=function(){
       test.style.width="120px";
   }
</script>
```

when the input's width change,the setter function can be triggered in IE11 and FireFox,but it can not work in chrome.

Comment: Perhaps you explain what you want to achieve so we do not have an  X/Y problem

Comment: @mplungjan the title is pretty clear, it doesn't work in chrome only http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/5626t03L/1/

Comment: I understand, but what is the point of the code in the first place? And why not use this.style.width ?

Comment: To call the setter function when the style property is changed. The setter function can add additional functionality when setting properties, kind of like a proxy.

Comment: @mplungjan the question marked as duplicate does not address the same issue by the way.

Comment: @mplungjan I'm new to use JavaScript

Comment: So it was a duplicate but of [Override property CSSStyleDeclaration.textShadow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225149/override-property-cssstyledeclaration-textshadow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like an old bug in Chrome:

> In chrome, unlike other browsers, CSSStyleDeclaration is a function rather than an object.

- [90335 - It seems that 'Object.defineProperty' does not work on 'CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype' property.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=90335)
- [89697 -  CSSStyleDeclaration report incorrect descriptor](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=89697)

Related

- [Override property CSSStyleDeclaration.textShadow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225149/override-property-cssstyledeclaration-textshadow)